# Putting Quote Marks around Text with STRING_AGG

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query with sample data

```
select  
    (
        SELECT  STRING_AGG(TRIM(innerAgg.Result), '" - "')
        FROM
        (
            SELECT  DISTINCT
                value
            FROM    STRING_SPLIT(STRING_AGG(t1.[Sample Values], '-'), '-')
        ) AS innerAgg(Result)
    ) as [Sample Values]
from 
(
    select
        'abc' as [Sample Values]
    union all
    select
        'def'
    union all
    select
        'ghi'
) t1
```

It returns the results as:

```
abc" - "def" - "ghi
```

How could I get the results as:

```
"abc" - "def" - "ghi"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add them in the outer select:

```
select  '"' +
    (
        SELECT  STRING_AGG(TRIM(innerAgg.Result), '" - "')
        FROM
        (
            SELECT  DISTINCT
                value
            FROM    STRING_SPLIT(STRING_AGG(t1.[Sample Values], '-'), '-')
        ) AS innerAgg(Result)
    )  + '"'  as [Sample Values]
from 
(
    select
        'abc' as [Sample Values]
    union all
    select
        'def'
    union all
    select
        'ghi'
) t1
```

or add the quotes where you are preforming the `DISTINCT`:

```
select  
    (
        SELECT  STRING_AGG(TRIM(innerAgg.Result), ' - ')
        FROM
        (
            SELECT  DISTINCT
                CONCAT('"', value, '"')
            FROM    STRING_SPLIT(STRING_AGG(t1.[Sample Values], '-'), '-')
        ) AS innerAgg(Result)
    ) as [Sample Values]
from 
(
    select
        'abc' as [Sample Values]
    union all
    select
        'def'
    union all
    select
        'ghi'
) t1
```